# Is a generic type argument of a given type

Tags: c#

How do you determine whether a generic type argument is of a given type? This is what I have, but it seems hacky to instantiate the type just to test its type.

```
public void LogAllTheThings<T>()
    where T : class, new()
{
    if (new T() is Widget)
    {
       // Log widget-specific fields
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (T is Widget)`. But it's better to avoid such conversion

Comment: surely if you're using generics then half the point is that you don't really care what the type is

Comment: `typeof(T)` is never `ISomething`. It is `Type`.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski That gives an error: `'T' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`